how to keep the bind relation ship when migration kubernetes pv and pvc
I have build a new kubenetes cluster(v1.29) recently. Now I want to migration the legacy cluster(v1.29) pv and pvc to new kubernetes cluster. This is how I do it:
kubectl get pv -o yaml --all-namespaces > reddwarf-pv.yaml
kubectl --kubeconfig=/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.kube/admin.conf apply -f reddwarf-pv.yaml

kubectl get pvc -o yaml --all-namespaces > reddwarf-pvc.yaml
kubectl --kubeconfig=/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.kube/admin.conf apply -f reddwarf-pvc.yaml

this works but now I found a issue that the pv and pvc in new cluster lost the bind relation ship, the pv shows status release and the pvc shows statue lost. Am I missing something? what should I do to fixed this issue and keeep the bind relation shup correctly? This is the pv:

and this is the pvc:

this is part of the pv and pvc yaml define:
    - apiVersion: v1
  kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
  metadata:
    annotations:
      kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
        {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"PersistentVolumeClaim","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"chat-server-service-pv-claim","namespace":"reddwarf-pro"},"spec":{"accessModes":["ReadWriteOnce"],"resources":{"requests":{"storage":"8Gi"}},"volumeMode":"Filesystem","volumeName":"nfs-chat-server-service-pv"},"status":{"accessModes":["ReadWriteOnce"],"capacity":{"storage":"8Gi"},"phase":"Bound"}}
      pv.kubernetes.io/bind-completed: "yes"
    creationTimestamp: "2023-04-09T05:55:15Z"
    finalizers:
    - kubernetes.io/pvc-protection
    name: chat-server-service-pv-claim
    namespace: reddwarf-pro
    resourceVersion: "116598462"
    uid: 6b4f1dbc-a82c-4e3c-b0a1-12fc819391a6
  spec:
    accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
    resources:
      requests:
        storage: 8Gi
    volumeMode: Filesystem
    volumeName: nfs-chat-server-service-pv
  status:
    accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
    capacity:
      storage: 8Gi
    phase: Bound

this is the pvc look like:
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
  metadata:
    annotations:
      pv.kubernetes.io/bind-completed: "yes"
      pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: "yes"
    creationTimestamp: "2021-08-05T05:26:29Z"
    finalizers:
    - kubernetes.io/pvc-protection
    labels:
      app.kubernetes.io/component: master
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: cruise-redis
      app.kubernetes.io/name: redis
    name: redis-data-cruise-redis-master-0
    namespace: reddwarf-cache
    resourceVersion: "334166"
    uid: 57bdca30-64b9-45a5-af93-86c5ab3fba5c
  spec:
    accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
    resources:
      requests:
        storage: 8Gi
    volumeMode: Filesystem
    volumeName: nfs-reddwarf-redis-master-pv0
  status:
    accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
    capacity:
      storage: 8Gi
    phase: Bound

I have tried to edit the pv's claimref uid and resource version to match the new cluster's pvc seems did not work.

As per the official document you Delete the claimRef entry from PV specs, so as new PVC can bind to it. This should make the PV Available.
And also please execute the below command

kubectl patch pv pv-for-rabbitmq -p '{"spec":{"claimRef": null}}'

I hope the above information helps.

this command works, but I still wonder why delete claimref this bond work? I have so many PV and PVC and withtout claimref, how does the PV know which PVC should bond. Normally I think the PV found the pair PVC by the claimRef claim.

As per your query without the claimRef field , kubernetes can use other mechanisms to determine which PVC should be bound to a PV and some of them are labels and selectors , manual binding, default binding etc.
Refer to this documentation to know more about the labels and selectors and please let us know if it is useful.
